# No buildtime speedup after using Incredibuild with Visual Studio Solution file

Tags: visual-studio, build, devenv, incredibuild

I am trying to use Xoreax Incredibuild(v 8.01) to buid LLVM solution file using “BuildConsole” but I am not seeing any speedup in the build times.

- In the LLVM logs I can see a message **Maximum number of concurrent builds reached. Waiting for a build to complete**
- I believe this could be the reason that I am not seeing the benefit of using Incredibuild to build LLVM.
- Version of Visual Studio used by Incredibuild to build the solution file is 2015.

Has anyone else encountered such a message and if so what is the reason/solution?

I have also tried using **IB_profile.xml** file to build LLVM and see if it helps in getting rid of the above message but 
I am seeing the same message when using XML file to  integrate Incredibuild with LLVM.

This is the **Make command** that I am using **to build LLVM with Incredibuild**:

```
BuildConsole LLVM.sln /build "Release|x64" /prj="INSTALL" /AvoidLocal=On /profile=IB_profile.xml
```

This is the content of **IB_profile.xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Profile FormatVersion="1">
  <Tools>
    <Tool Filename="devenv"  AllowIntercept="true" AllowRemote="true" AllowPredictedBatch="true" VCCompiler="true" OutputFileMasks="*.exe,*.dll" />
    <Tool Filename="cl" AllowRemote="true" AllowPredictedBatch="true" VCCompiler="true" OutputFileMasks="*.exe,*.dll" />
  </Tools>
</Profile>
```

Below is the snippet of **LLVM logs**:

```
BuildConsole LLVM.sln /build "Release|x64" /prj="INSTALL" /AvoidLocal=On /profile=IB_profile.xml


-----------------------------------------------------------------
Build Acceleration Console 8.2 (build 1885)
Copyright (C) 2001-2017 Xoreax Software Ltd. All rights reserved.
-----------------------------------------------------------------


-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS


-- Build files have been written to: C:/TEMP/rohit/win64/LLVM
BuildConsole LLVM.sln /build "Release|x64" /prj="INSTALL" /AvoidLocal=On /profile=IB_profile.xml

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Build Acceleration Console 8.2 (build 1885)
Copyright (C) 2001-2017 Xoreax Software Ltd. All rights reserved.
-----------------------------------------------------------------



Maximum number of concurrent builds reached.
Waiting for a build to complete...
--------------------Build System Warning---------------------------------------
Predicted Execution mode automatically disabled:
    Predicted Execution mode cannot be set together with DisableStdOutIdentify flag.

    Please note the disabled predicted execution feature has no effect on build integrity.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Active code page: 437
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25420.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: LLVMSupport, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: LLVMTableGen, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: obj.llvm-tblgen, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: LLVMMC, Configuration: Release x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: LLVMMCDisassembler, Configuration: Release x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: LLVMMCParser, Configuration: Release x64 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: LLVMOption, Configuration: Release x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: LLVMDebugInfoDWARF, Configuration: Release x64 ------
9>------ Build started: Project: LLVMSymbolize, Configuration: Release x64 ------
10>------ Build started: Project: LTO_exports, Configuration: Release x64 ------
11>------ Build started: Project: LLVMDebugInfoPDB, Configuration: Release x64 ------
12>------ Build started: Project: LLVMLineEditor, Configuration: Release x64 ------
13>------ Build started: Project: count, Configuration: Release x64 ------
14>------ Build started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Release x64 ------
15>------ Build started: Project: gtest_main, Configuration: Release x64 ------
16>------ Build started: Project: llvm-PerfectShuffle, Configuration: Release x64 ------
```

Answer (score 0):

My name is Yoni Davidson and I am from IncrediBuild support team.
Building the LLVM Solution using BuildConsoel shouldn't require profile.xml since it is a Visual Studio Solution and IncrediBuild should handle it.
Therefore, it is possible that either you dont have remote machines (Helpers) and/or perhaps you dont have enough parallel tasks so the performance is more or less as you have with Visual Studio since everything runs locally.
The "Maximum number of concurrent builds reached" means that you are trying to start another build with IncrediBuild while the previous one is still running. This is not allowed and therefore, you receive this message. In any case, this is not the reason for the build performance you have.

I will be happy to assist you with this problem so I suggest that you will contact us directly: support@incredibuild.com or simply right click on IncrediBuild tray icon -> contact support.

Looking forward hearing from you.